# This solution contains one or more assemblies targeted for the global assembly cache

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, gac

I am having a SharePoint site which is deployed through SharePoint powershell. the wsp is build through visual studio 2013.

All my projects in the solution are not Signed assemblies(project->right Click->properties->Signing->Sign the assemblies check box is unchecked). I am taking the wsp of my solution by publishing it and deploying it to the SharePoint using SharePoint powershell.

When I try to do this, I am getting the following error:

[image]

When I googled for the solution. Many of them are suggesting to Check the 'Sign the assemblies' check box. which I don't want to do, because I am facing some other issues with some packages install through Nugget.

Answer (score 1):

Sign the Libraries of the Solution

Go to **Properties** of the Project then Click **Signing** tab and then Check the **Sign the Libraries** Options and create a new Strong Name file with or without password and then Rebuild and Deploy.

[image]